# BoundingRegion also bounding outliers. Can I apply a standard deviation filter?

Tags: regions, computational-geometry

I'm using BoundingRegion to classify a list of data points using ellipsoid shapes. BoundingRegion tends to make sure that all points fit in the shape, including outlier points. Is there a way to control the accuracy of the bounding region and to weight it towards the centre?

I initially minimised the Euclidean distance to find a circle's centroid but shifted to BoundingRegion as I didn't want to play around with minimising ellipsoid rotations in addition to determining the ellipsoid x/y radii individually.

Comment: `BoundingRegion` is supposed to capture all the points. Instead you should consider fitting a `MultinormalDistribution` around your data and creating a 95% 'confidence ellipsoid' around it.

Comment: Another approach might be to use `FindAnomalies` or `DeleteAnomalies`, and then using `BoundingRegion` on the resulting points.

Comment: Thanks both. Both options work well for what is needed, although it seems that DeleteAnomalies is a bit more CPU intensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following @flinty's advice and reading up on the MultivariateStatistics [tutorial](http://https%20:%20//%20%20%20reference.wolfram.com/language/MultivariateStatistics/tutorial/%20%20%20MultivariateStatistics.html):

```
<< MultivariateStatistics`
temp = pts[[1]]; 
q = EllipsoidQuantile[temp, 0.95]; (*0.95 confidence*)
Show[Graphics[q]]
```

Gives a nice representation of an ellipsoid fit to the data.